# How to send upstream messages using FCM and PhoneGap

Tags: cordova, firebase, phonegap-plugins, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using [cordova-plugin-fcm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-fcm) plugin to implement FCM push messaging in my phonegap app.

I am unable to find a way to send upstream messages(using XMPP protocol) from my app. I referred [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/upstream) Firebase doc and it explains how to send upstream message from native android client. Is there a way to send XMPP upstream messages using phoneGap/Cordova?

Comment: Hey, were you able to send upstream messages using cordova-plugin-fcm?